# LWC UI is not updating even though property is updated

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on an LWC component wherein even though the property is changing, UI is being updated.
I have a main component with two internal components wholesaler lookup component and warehouse lookup component. The records are being fetched in wholesaler lookup component, they are visible in the UI but the UI is being updated and no update it visible on the UI.
Warehouse lookup component and wholesaler lookup component have similar codebase only.

If I enter a search term for Wholesaler Lookup component, fetchFilterWholesalers wire function is being called and records are being retrieved and resultList is updated. But the UI displaying the resultList is not being displayed.

**Main Component**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Lightning Web Component using Quick Action">
        <div class="slds-table_edit_container slds-is-relative slds-var-p-around_medium">
            <table aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-table slds-no-cell-focus slds-table_bordered slds-table_edit slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_resizable-cols " role="grid" style="width:100%" aria-label="Example default inline edit table with cell focused">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <!--<th class="slds-hidden" scope="col" style="width:0.1rem">
                        <span id="column-group-header1" class="slds-assistive-text">Line Item Id</span>
                    </th>-->
                    <th class="" scope="col" style="width:2rem">
                        <div class="slds-th__action slds-th__action_form">
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Account Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">Product Name</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Account Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Product Name">National ID</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Name" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Wholesaler</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th aria-label="Quantity" aria-sort="none" class="slds-is-resizable slds-is-sortable" scope="col" style="width:8.75rem">
                        <a class="slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset" href="#" role="button" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: </span>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Quantity">Warehouse</span>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody > 
            <template for:each={itemList} for:item="currentItem"> 
                <tr aria-selected="false" class="slds-hint-parent" key={currentItem.index}  data-key={currentItem.index} >
                    <!--<td class="slds-hidden" role="gridcell" scope="row" data-label="Sr No" >
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.recordId} data-id={currentItem.index} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>-->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit slds-var-m-horizontal_medium" style="vertical-align: middle;" role="gridcell" scope="row" data-label="checkbox" >
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="" name="checkbox" value=true data-id={currentItem.index}></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Product Name Cell -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit slds-cell-wrap" role="gridcell">
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.productName} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Product National ID Cell -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell">
                        <span class="slds-var-m-horizontal_medium">
                            <div class="slds-hidden">
                                <p><lightning-formatted-text class="slds-hidden" value={currentItem.recordId} data-id={currentItem.recordId} ></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                            </div>
                            <p><lightning-formatted-text value={currentItem.nationalID}></lightning-formatted-text></p>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- Wholesaler Lookup -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell" scope="row">
                        <!--<lightning-combobox
                            name="wholesaler"
                            value={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            placeholder="Select Wholesaler"
                            options={wholesalerList}
                            onchange={handleWholesalerChange} 
                            row-index={currentItem.index} 
                            data-id={currentItem.index}></lightning-combobox>-->
                        <c-s-c-t_-wholesaler-lookup-component 
                        name = "wholesaler"
                        label = ""
                        placeholder = "Search Wholesaler"
                        default-record-id ={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                        config-id="a4W7a000000CZQLEA4"
                        onlookupupdate={handleWholesalerChange}
                        row-index={currentItem.index} 
                        data-id={currentItem.index}></c-s-c-t_-wholesaler-lookup-component>

                    </td>
                    <!-- Warehouse Lookup -->
                    <td class="slds-cell-edit" role="gridcell" scope="row">
                        <!--
                        <lightning-combobox
                            name="warehouse"
                            value={currentItem.warehouseId}
                            placeholder="Select Warehouse"
                            options={dependentWarehouses}
                            onchange={handleWarehouseChange} ></lightning-combobox>
                        -->
                        <c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component 
                            name = "warehouse"
                            label = ""
                            placeholder = "Search Warehouse"
                            default-record-id ={currentItem.warehouseId}
                            data-wholesalerid ={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            wholesaler-id ={currentItem.wholesalerId}
                            selected-wholesaler-id ={selectedWholesalerId}
                            onlookupupdate={lookupRecord}
                            row-index={currentItem.index} 
                            data-id={currentItem.index}></c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component >
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update" onclick={updateLineItems} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

**Main Component JS**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import initRecords from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getLineItemsTest';
//import getWholesalers from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getWholesalers';

export default class SCT_WholesalerCongaCartComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track data;
    @track columns;
    @track itemList= [];
    @track wholesalerList;
    @track wholesalers;
    @track warehousesMap;
    @track selectedWholesaler;
    @track dependentWarehouses;
    @track lineItemList;
    @track retrievedData;
    @track selectedWholesalerId = '';
    keyIndex = 1;
    
    @wire(initRecords, { cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4' })
    wiredLineItems({data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.retrievedData = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            
            let tempList = [];
            let tempLineItemList = [];
            for(let key in data){
                
                var newItem = [{
                    index : this.keyIndex ,recordId : this.retrievedData[key].recordId , productName : this.retrievedData[key].productName , 
                    nationalID : this.retrievedData[key].nationalID , wholesalerId : this.retrievedData[key].wholesalerId , 
                    warehouseId : this.retrievedData[key].warehouseId
                }];

                /*
                tempLineItemList.push({index : this.keyIndex ,recordId : this.data[key].recordId , productName : this.data[key].productName , 
                nationalID : this.data[key].nationalID , wholesalerId : this.data[key].wholesalerId , warehouseId : this.data[key].warehouseId });
                */
               
                this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(newItem);
                
                tempList.push(this.itemList[key].recordId);
                
                this.keyIndex++;
            }

            this.lineItemList = tempList;

        } else if(error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.itemList = undefined;
        }
    }

    /*
    @wire(getWholesalers, { cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4'}) 
    wiredWholesalers({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.wholesalers = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            let tempOptions = [];

            for(let key in data){
                tempOptions.push({label : data[key].Name, value : data[key].Id});
            }
            this.wholesalerList = tempOptions;

        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.wholesalers = undefined;
        }
    }
    */

    /*
    @wire(getWarehouses , {cartId : 'a4W7a000000CZQLEA4'})
    wiredWarehouses({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.warehousesMap = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            for(let key in warehousesMap) {
                this.warehousesMap[key].values.forEach(option => {
                    dependentWarehouses.push({
                        label: option.locationName,
                        value: option.locationId 
                    });
                });
            }
            console.log('warehousesMap : '+warehousesMap);
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }*/

    handleWholesalerChange(event) {
        
        alert('Wholesaler Updated is ' +  JSON.stringify(event.detail.selectedRecord));
       
        /*
        this.selectedWholesaler =  event.detail.selectedRecord.wholesalerId;
        this.selectedWholesalerId = this.selectedWholesaler;

        let dependValues = [];

        console.log(this.selectedWholesaler);
        console.log('event.detail prod',JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log('event detail dataset', JSON.stringify(event.target.dataset.id));
        const index = event.target.dataset.id;

        const checkbox = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-id="'+index+'"]');
        
        let curRow = this.itemList.find(item => index == item.index);
        curRow.wholesalerId = this.selectedWholesaler;
        */

        /*
        const warehouseLookup =  this.template.querySelectr('c-s-c-t_-warehouses-lookup-component[data-id="'+index+'"]');
        warehouseLookup.setAttribute('data-wholesalerid',this.selectedWholesaler);
        */
       
        /*
        console.log(warehousesMap);
        console.log('dependentWarehouses : '+dependentWarehouses);

        if(this.selectedWholesaler) {
            this.warehousesMap[this.selectedWholesaler].values.forEach(singleWarehouse => {
                dependValues.push({
                    label: singleWarehouse.locationName,
                    value: singleWarehouse.locationId
                });
            });
            this.dependentWarehouses = dependValues;
            console.log(this.dependentWarehouses);
        }*/
    }

    lookupRecord(event){
        alert('Selected Record Value on Parent Component is ' +  JSON.stringify(event.detail.selectedRecord));
    }

    handleWarehouseChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    updateLineItems(event) {
        console.log('Save Button Clicked!!!');
        console.log('Save Button Clicked Again!!!');
        console.log('list variable ',this.lineItemList);
        console.log(this.lineItemList.length);
        for(let i=0;i<this.lineItemList.length;i++) {
            this.lineItemId = this.lineItemList[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Wholesaler Lookup Component**

```
<!--
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
-->
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult}  data-source="lookupContainer">     
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">{label}</label>
          <div class="lookupContainerWholesaler slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox"> 
           <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
              <div class="searchBoxWrapperWholesaler slds-show">
                <!--Lookup Input Field-->
                <lightning-input                   
                   type="search"
                   data-source="searchInputField"
                   onclick={toggleResult}
                   onchange={handleKeyChange}
                   is-loading={isSearchLoading}
                   value={searchKey}
                   variant="label-hidden"
                   placeholder={placeholder}
               ></lightning-input>  
              </div>
              
            <!--Lookup Selected record pill container start-->  
            <div class="pillDivWholesaler slds-hide">        
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-combobox__input-entity-icon">
                <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>  
              </span>
              <input type="text"
                     id="combobox-id-1"
                     value={selectedRecord.wholesalerName}       
                     class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value"
                     readonly
                     />
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option">
              <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="close icon" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-icon> 
             </button>
            </div>  
            </div>
        
            <!-- lookup search result part start-->
            <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-5" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                <template for:each={resultList} for:item="obj">
                    <li key={obj.wholesalerId} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div data-recid={obj.wholesalerId} onclick={handelSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                        <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                        <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                        </span>
                        </span>
                        <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                        <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.wholesalerName}</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </template>
                <!--ERROR msg, if there is no records..-->
                <template if:false={hasRecords}>
                  <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records Found....</li>
                </template>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </template>
```

**Wholesaler Lookup JS**

```
/*
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
*/
import { LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
// import apex method from salesforce module 
import fetchDefaultedWholesaler from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getDefaultedWholesaler';
import fetchFilterWholesalers from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getSearchedWholesalers';

const DELAY = 300; // dealy apex callout timing in miliseconds  

export default class CustomLookupLwc extends LightningElement {
    // public properties with initial default values 
    @api label = 'custom lookup label';
    @api placeholder = 'search...';
    @api iconName = 'standard:account';
    @api sObjectApiName = 'Account';
    @api defaultRecordId = '';
    @api configId = '';


    // private properties 
    @track resultList = []; // to store list of returned records   
    hasRecords = true; 
    searchKey=''; // to store input field value    
    wholesalerActualId=''; // to store input field value
    cartId = '';
    isSearchLoading = false; // to control loading spinner  
    delayTimeout;
    selectedRecord = {}; // to store selected lookup record in object formate 

   // initial function to populate default selected lookup record if defaultRecordId provided  
    connectedCallback(){
        this.cartId = this.configId;
        console.log('defaultRecordId',this.defaultRecordId);
        console.log('cartId',this.cartId);
        if(this.defaultRecordId != ''){
            fetchDefaultedWholesaler({ wholesalerId: this.defaultRecordId })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('result' , result);
                if(result != null){
                    this.selectedRecord = result;
                    console.log('selectedRecord : ',this.selectedRecord);
                    this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('In Catch Block');
                this.error = error;
                this.selectedRecord = {};
            });
        }
    }

    // wire function property to fetch search record based on user input
    @wire(fetchFilterWholesalers, { cartId : '$cartId' , searchKey: '$searchKey'  })
     searchResult(value) {
        const { data, error } = value; // destructure the provisioned value
        this.isSearchLoading = false;
        if (data) {
            this.hasRecords = data.length == 0 ? false : true; 
            console.log('hasRecords : ',this.hasRecords);
            this.resultList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            console.log('resultList : ',this.resultList);
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log('(error---> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    };
       
    // update searchKey property on input field change  
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        // Debouncing this method: Do not update the reactive property as long as this function is
        // being called within a delay of DELAY. This is to avoid a very large number of Apex method calls.
        this.isSearchLoading = true;
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        const searchKey = event.target.value;

        console.log('searchKey',searchKey);

        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
        this.cartId = this.configId;
        console.log('searchKey',this.searchKey);
        console.log('cartId',this.cartId);
        }, DELAY);
    }

    // method to toggle lookup result section on UI 
    toggleResult(event){
        const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainerWholesaler');
        const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
        const whichEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-source');

        switch(whichEvent) {
            case 'searchInputField':
                clsList.add('slds-is-open');
               break;
            case 'lookupContainer':
                clsList.remove('slds-is-open');    
            break;                    
        }
    }

    // method to clear selected lookup record  
    handleRemove(){
        this.searchKey = '';    
        this.selectedRecord = {};
        
        console.log('in handleRemove');

        this.lookupUpdatehandler(undefined); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 
        
        console.log('after lookupUpdatehandler');

        // remove selected pill and display input field again 
        const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-hide');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-show');

        const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDivWholesaler');
        pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-show');
        pillDiv.classList.add('slds-hide');

        console.log('End lookupUpdatehandler');

    }

    // method to update selected record from search result 
    handelSelectedRecord(event){   
        var objId = event.target.getAttribute('data-recid'); // get selected record Id 
        console.log('objId',objId);
        this.selectedRecord = this.resultList.find(data => data.wholesalerId === objId); // find selected record from list 
        this.lookupUpdatehandler(this.selectedRecord); // update value on parent component as well from helper function 
        this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
    }

    /*COMMON HELPER METHOD STARTED*/

    handelSelectRecordHelper(){

        console.log('in handelSelectRecordHelper');


        this.template.querySelector('.lookupContainerWholesaler').classList.remove('slds-is-open');

        console.log('after lookupContainerWholesaler');

        const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-show');
        searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-hide');

        console.log('after searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        
        const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDivWholesaler');
        pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-hide');
        pillDiv.classList.add('slds-show');  
        
        console.log('finished handelSelectRecordHelper');
    }

    // send selected lookup record to parent component using custom event
    lookupUpdatehandler(value){    
        const oEvent = new CustomEvent('lookupupdate',
        {
            'detail': {selectedRecord: value}
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
}
```

--------UPDATED---------
Adding Screenshots of look and feel of the component
[image: LWC Component Loaded]

[image: Clicking on x bar to remove the selected option]

[image: Searching for a wholesaler with options listed]

Comment: Hi to be clear, these two are the same issue?

"The records are being fetched in wholesaler lookup component, they are visible in the UI but the UI is being updated and no update it visible on the UI." <br/>
AND <br/>
"If I enter a search term for Wholesaler Lookup component, fetchFilterWholesalers wire function is being called and records are being retrieved and resultList is updated. But the UI displaying the resultList is not being displayed." <br/>

So in the console you are getting the resultList, but not in the UI?

Comment: Hi @dbwood3, yes. These two are same issues only.

Comment: please provide minimal reproduceable code samples vs posting code dumps of your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying/refactoring some of your code.  This may fix it, but probably all it will do is move you closer to LWC by not editing the DOM directly.  LWC's containers create a structure that will frustrate you endlessly... embrace LWC and the shadow DOM!

Did you know that in LWC you can use properties for Classes? 'slds-show' and 'slds-hide' can be handled with the following code via properties.

So, instead of having
`<div class="containerName slds-show">` in your HTML and then in your JS search for the containerName and then changing the value of the property, eg :

```
handleWhatever() {    const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.containerName');
    const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;
    clsList.add('slds-show');
    clsList.remove('slds-hide');
    }
```

you can simply have:
HTML

```
<div class={className}>
```

JS

```
className = 'slds-hide'; //default value for the property

handleWhatever() {
   this.className = (className === 'slds-hide' ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide');
}
```

Cleaning the code up this way removes what gets me most of the time, and was the issue here... you transcribe a name wrong.  This keeps it simpler.

HTML

```
<!--
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
-->
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult}  data-source="lookupContainer">     
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">{label}</label>
          <!-- <div class="lookupContainerWholesaler slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">  -->
          <div class={lookupContainerClass} aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox"> 
           <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
              <!-- <div class="searchBoxWrapperWholesaler slds-show"> -->
              <div class={searchBoxClass}>
                <!--Lookup Input Field-->
                <lightning-input                   
                   type="search"
                   data-source="searchInputField"
                   onclick={toggleResult}
                   onchange={handleKeyChange}
                   is-loading={isSearchLoading}
                   value={searchKey}
                   variant="label-hidden"
                   placeholder={placeholder}
               ></lightning-input>  
              </div>
              
            <!--Lookup Selected record pill container start-->  
            <!-- <div class="pillDivWholesaler slds-hide">         -->
            <div class={pillClass}>        
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-combobox__input-entity-icon">
                <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="x-small" alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>  
              </span>
              <input type="text"
                     id="combobox-id-1"
                     value={selectedRecord.wholesalerName}       
                     class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value"
                     readonly
                     />
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option">
              <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="close icon" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-icon> 
             </button>
            </div>  
            </div>
        
            <!-- lookup search result part start-->
            <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-5" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                <template for:each={resultList} for:item="obj">
                    <li key={obj.wholesalerId} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div data-recid={obj.wholesalerId} onclick={handelSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                        <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                        <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                            <lightning-icon icon-name={iconName} size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                        </span>
                        </span>
                        <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                        <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.wholesalerName}</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </template>
                <!--ERROR msg, if there is no records..-->
                <template if:false={hasRecords}>
                  <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records Found....</li>
                </template>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </template>
```

JS

```
/*
API : 50
Source : lwcFactory.com
*/
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
// import apex method from salesforce module
import fetchDefaultedWholesaler from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getDefaultedWholesaler';
import fetchFilterWholesalers from '@salesforce/apex/SCT_CongaCartComponentController.getSearchedWholesalers';

const DELAY = 300; // dealy apex callout timing in miliseconds

const SLDS_IS_OPEN = ' slds-is-open'; //leading space needed
const SLDS_HIDE = 'slds-hide';
const SLDS_SHOW = 'slds-show';

export default class CustomLookupLwc extends LightningElement {
    // public properties with initial default values
    @api label = 'custom lookup label';
    @api placeholder = 'search...';
    @api iconName = 'standard:account';
    @api sObjectApiName = 'Account';
    @api defaultRecordId = '';
    @api configId = '';

    //class properties
    pillClass = SLDS_HIDE;
    searchBoxClass = SLDS_SHOW;
    lookupContainerClass =
        'slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click';

    // private properties
    @track resultList = []; // to store list of returned records
    hasRecords = true;
    searchKey = ''; // to store input field value
    wholesalerActualId = ''; // to store input field value
    cartId = '';
    isSearchLoading = false; // to control loading spinner
    delayTimeout;
    selectedRecord = {}; // to store selected lookup record in object formate

    // initial function to populate default selected lookup record if defaultRecordId provided
    connectedCallback() {
        this.cartId = this.configId;
        console.log('defaultRecordId', this.defaultRecordId);
        console.log('cartId', this.cartId);
        if (this.defaultRecordId != '') {
            fetchDefaultedWholesaler({ wholesalerId: this.defaultRecordId })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log('result', result);
                    if (result != null) {
                        this.selectedRecord = result;
                        console.log('selectedRecord : ', this.selectedRecord);
                        this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('In Catch Block');
                    this.error = error;
                    this.selectedRecord = {};
                });
        }
    }

    // wire function property to fetch search record based on user input
    @wire(fetchFilterWholesalers, {
        cartId: '$cartId',
        searchKey: '$searchKey'
    })
    searchResult(value) {
        const { data, error } = value; // destructure the provisioned value
        this.isSearchLoading = false;
        if (data) {
            this.hasRecords = data.length == 0 ? false : true;
            console.log('hasRecords : ', this.hasRecords);
            this.resultList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('resultList : ', this.resultList);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('(error---> ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    // update searchKey property on input field change
    handleKeyChange(event) {
        // Debouncing this method: Do not update the reactive property as long as this function is
        // being called within a delay of DELAY. This is to avoid a very large number of Apex method calls.
        this.isSearchLoading = true;
        window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
        const searchKey = event.target.value;

        console.log('searchKey', searchKey);

        this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchKey = searchKey;
            this.cartId = this.configId;
            console.log('searchKey', this.searchKey);
            console.log('cartId', this.cartId);
        }, DELAY);
    }

    // method to toggle lookup result section on UI
    toggleResult(event) {
        // lookupINputContainerWholesaler DOES NOT EXIST IN HTML YOU PROBALLY WANT lookupContainerWholesaler
        // found in my refactor
        // const lookupInputContainer = this.template.querySelector('.lookupInputContainerWholesaler');
        // const clsList = lookupInputContainer.classList;

        const whichEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-source');

        switch (whichEvent) {
            case 'searchInputField':
                this.lookupContainerClass = this.lookupContainerClass.concat(
                    SLDS_IS_OPEN
                );
                break;
            case 'lookupContainer':
                this.lookupContainerClass = this.lookupContainerClass.replace(
                    SLDS_IS_OPEN,
                    ''
                );
                break;
        }
    }

    // method to clear selected lookup record
    handleRemove() {
        this.searchKey = '';
        this.selectedRecord = {};

        console.log('in handleRemove');

        this.lookupUpdatehandler(undefined); // update value on parent component as well from helper function

        console.log('after lookupUpdatehandler');

        // remove selected pill and display input field again
        // const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        // searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-hide');
        // searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-show');
        this.searchBoxClass = SLDS_SHOW;

        // const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDivWholesaler');
        // pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-show');
        // pillDiv.classList.add('slds-hide');
        this.pillClass = SLDS_HIDE;

        console.log('End lookupUpdatehandler');
    }

    // method to update selected record from search result
    handelSelectedRecord(event) {
        var objId = event.target.getAttribute('data-recid'); // get selected record Id
        console.log('objId', objId);
        this.selectedRecord = this.resultList.find(
            data => data.wholesalerId === objId
        ); // find selected record from list
        this.lookupUpdatehandler(this.selectedRecord); // update value on parent component as well from helper function
        this.handelSelectRecordHelper(); // helper function to show/hide lookup result container on UI
    }

    /*COMMON HELPER METHOD STARTED*/

    handelSelectRecordHelper() {
        console.log('in handelSelectRecordHelper');
        this.lookupContainerClass = this.lookupContainerClass.replace(
            SLDS_IS_OPEN,
            ''
        );
        console.log('after lookupContainerWholesaler');
        this.searchBoxClass = SLDS_HIDE;
        console.log('after searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        this.pillClass = SLDS_SHOW;
        console.log('finished handelSelectRecordHelper');

        // this.template.querySelector('.lookupContainerWholesaler').classList.remove('slds-is-open');
        // this.lookupContainerClass = this.lookupContainerClass.replace(SLDS_IS_OPEN, '');

        // const searchBoxWrapper = this.template.querySelector('.searchBoxWrapperWholesaler');
        // searchBoxWrapper.classList.remove('slds-show');
        // searchBoxWrapper.classList.add('slds-hide');

        // const pillDiv = this.template.querySelector('.pillDivWholesaler');
        // pillDiv.classList.remove('slds-hide');
        // pillDiv.classList.add('slds-show');
    }

    // send selected lookup record to parent component using custom event
    lookupUpdatehandler(value) {
        const oEvent = new CustomEvent('lookupupdate', {
            detail: { selectedRecord: value }
        });

        this.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, I can't run this code.  It does make it through the Static Code Check, let me know if we still have an issue, and I will take a look again!

Comment: btw, you don't need to paint Lists of SObjects with a @track...

Comment: you might want to explain the key differences with your code vs the OP's . Otherwise, it is what it is, a code dump.

Comment: Hi @dbwood3 Thanks a lot! That was exactly the issue. Thanks! A completely unrelated question though, I'm trying to develop a functionality wherein if the value on wholesaler lookup component is removed, then, if value on warehouse lookup component(is selected and present), should also be removed. Is it possible somehow? And how can that be achieved? If needed, I'll share all the components in github repo.

Comment: @gils, I wanted to see if it worked before I waxed on about my great ideas... lol.   I'll add details now that it works.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar, I'm so glad it worked!  Can you mark it as solved and vote it up?  Thank you.

OK, in your second issue.... value on wholesaler lookup component is removed, by what?

Comment: @dbwood3 Yes. I'll upvote it and mark it and resolved. Regarding the question, value on wholesaler component is removed by user by clicking on x button. In the HTML, for the icon-name="utility:close" tag, there's on removefunction on Click which removes the selected lookup value.

Comment: @dbwood3 I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation points to chat in the room. Is there another way we can communicate?

Comment: we'll do it here... the SO can move it later!   I thought my upvote would give you enough to do it!


ohh... let me restate:

The User should be able to click a button and remove a warehouse from resultList (and close whatever is closed).  Can you drop in a screenshot of what this looks like?  Just the area around the pillClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131758/discussion-between-dbwood3-and-akhilesh-kumar).

Comment: you can now talk in chat, @AkhileshKumar :-). I upvoted your other question

Comment: @dbwood3 thanks =)